# Why does throwing an error in a Promises catch callback result in unhandled promise rejection?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to implement a looping structure via recursion that uses promises. With this code:

```
(function a(i) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (i < 10) {
            (function b() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    if (1 != 1) {
                        resolve();
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('error from b'); // This works
                    };
                });
            })().then(function() {
                    i++;
                    resolve(a(i));
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    reject(new Error(error)); // This does work
                    // throw new Error(error); // Why doesn't this work?
                });
        } else {
            console.log('loop complete');
        };
    });
})(0).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log('done');
});
```

I find that if I throw an error within a `Promise` constructor, that the error is automatically handled and seemingly passed to the `reject` function. But if I throw an error in the callback passed to the `catch` function, then the error isn't handled by the parent `catch`.

Why is this?

Comment: Just return the error.

Comment: This code is a total mess to follow.  You should never have `new Promise()` and `.then()` handlers inside a promise executor callback - never.   If you write this code properly, you will not have this problem or confusion. 
 The reason your `throw` doesn't work is because the `.catch()` is async and thus the outer promise executor has already returned and thus the `throw` is not actually in that callback any more.

Comment: I agree - I'm new to promises and hence they are messy. What is the `outer promise executor`?

Comment: @JaredSmith that doesn't work

Comment: @ZachSmith doesn't work for what? Do you want to re-throw? Because you can't do that as jfriend00 pointed out, synchronously.